# Merging two excerpt functions to work with conditions

Tags: php, functions, excerpt

I have two functions that affect `the_excerpt`:

```
// Grab First Paragraph Of Text And Ignore Images For Excerpt
    function awesome_excerpt($text, $raw_excerpt) {
        if( ! $raw_excerpt ) {
            $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
            $text = substr( $content, 0, strpos( $content, '</p>' ) + 4 );
        }
        $text = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $text); 
        return $text;
    }
    add_filter( 'wp_trim_excerpt', 'awesome_excerpt', 10, 2 );

function excerpt($limit) {
        $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
        if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
            array_pop($excerpt);
            $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'...';
          } else {
            $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
          } 
        $excerpt = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]`','',$excerpt);
        return $excerpt;
    }
```

Now, on my `index.php`, those posts show the first paragraph of the post. I am also trying to show the excerpt when you click into a posts in an area called Related Posts. In Related Posts I want it to show a limit of x characters.

On the `index.php` I am leaving it as `the_excerpt`, but on my Related Posts I'm calling it with `<?php echo excerpt(25);?>`. This is what the markup looks like when I'm calling it for the Related Posts like:

```
<div class="recent-meta-excerpt">
   <?php echo excerpt(25);?>
   <a class="read-more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

It's outputting like this:

```
 <div class="recent-meta-excerpt">
       <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout....
       <a class="read-more" href="http://www.stepyouraimup.com/blog/no-featured-image/">Read More <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
       </p>
    </div>
```

But I don't want the `<a>` inside. When I'm calling `the_excerpt` on the Related Posts the `<a>` it's inside of the `<p>`. On the main posts in index.php it's wrapping the first paragraph from the post into a `<p>`, this is correct. I would like to do the same for the excerpt on Related Posts, but it shouldn't have the `<a>` inside of it. If it's outside of the call why is it being included inside?

If you'd like a live example click [here](http://www.stepyouraimup.com/blog/) to view my blog and click a post to see the Related Posts.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on where in the loop you call `excerpt()` wpautop might be creating the `<p>...</p>` wrapper.  In that case, you could wrap `$excerpt` with `<p>...</p>` before returning it.

Edit:  Try this approach `<?php echo excerpt(25)."\n";?>` (or possibly `"\n\n"`) to change the behavior.

in function `awesome_excerpt()` you have `$text = substr( $content, 0, strpos( $content, '</p>' ) + 4 );` So, `$text` will have to contain a beginning `<p>`.  That is likely causing what you describe.  Add `str_ireplace('<p>', '', $excerpt)` in `function excerpt()` before calling `explode`.

In the current code shown in your question it's unclear where `function excerpt()` is being called.

Why not just use the `excerpt_length` filter to modify the length of the excerpt?  From the [Codex](https://wordpress.org/search/excerpt_length):

`function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 25;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );`

Comment: I tried using what was in the codex, but I only want the excerpt to show x characters in certain areas, that being wherever I call the excerpt when I'm getting Recent Posts. On the main blog, index.php, I want it to pull the first paragraph of the post.

Comment: So, what happens if you remove the starting `<p>` from `$text`?

Comment: not entirely sure how to do that, I grabbed both functions from two separate tutorials. My php skills are super weak to see where that `<p>` is. I only see I can edit the closing tag.

Comment: Well, the preferred way would be to use a debugger.  Without that the hardcore way is to add `echo $text; die;` right after `$text = substr( $content, 0, strpos( $content, '</p>' ) + 4 );`. The value of `$text` will be displayed and WP stops.  Copy the value from the screen and store it somewhere then delete `echo $text; die;`